# Set up Codeblocks (Linux Mint) for X Plane 11 SDK

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks, linux-mint

I have started to (partly) use CB (for plugin development for flight sim XPlane 11 based on its SDK) under Linux (Mint) instead of W10. With some help I could get the SDK with CB running under W10, however, so far I could not manage to get this working under Linux and would be very grateful for some help.
I have set up CB under LM as follows:
-No changes to global compiler settings, i.e. automatic compiler detection usr/=> C++ compiler = g++

- The Project build options are set as shown in the below pics
  When compiling I get an error message as follows
  [Build targets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAywa.png)
  [Project build options; #defines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvkg6.png)
  [Search directories in Project build settings (same for Linker search directories)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYRwr.png)

There is a description of basic settings/steps for using the SDK here:[enter link description here](https://developer.x-plane.com/article/building-and-installing-plugins/)

From this description I have neglegted all what is to do with 32 bit development. I am not sure whether I have put the linker command-line option in the right place in CB (Other linker options)

In case of need (for testing?) a complete sample project including the SDK can be found here:[download link is under the pic](https://developer.x-plane.com/code-sample/hello-world-sdk-3/)

In this respect perhaps somebody could explain how to use the make file in the sample project with CB. I am not very familiar with that, however, believe to understand that it contains some basic project settings.

Thank you very much up-front for possible help.

Here is the error message I get:

```
> g++ -Wall -O2 -DXPLM200=1 -DXPLM210=1 -DXPLM300=1 -DXPLM301=1 -DXPLM302=1 -DXPLM303=1 -DLIN = 1 -DIBM=0 -DAPL=0 -I/home/shj/Dokumente/HelloWorld/SDK/CHeaders/Widgets -I/home/shj/Dokumente/HelloWorld/SDK/CHeaders/Wrappers -I/home/shj/Dokumente/HelloWorld/SDK/CHeaders/XPLM -c /home/shj/Dokumente/HelloWorld/Hello-World-SDK-3.cpp -o obj/Release/HelloWorld/Hello-World-SDK-3.o
g++ -shared -L/home/shj/Dokumente/HelloWorld/SDK/CHeaders/Widgets -L/home/shj/Dokumente/HelloWorld/SDK/CHeaders/Wrappers -L/home/shj/Dokumente/HelloWorld/SDK/CHeaders/XPLM obj/Release/HelloWorld/Hello-World-SDK-3.o  -o bin/Release/liblin.so -s -shared -rdynamic -nodefaultlibs -undefined_warning -lGL -lGLU  
g++: error: =: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
g++: error: 1: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))<
```

Comment: What error messages do you get? Please [edit] your question to copy-paste them (in full and complete) *as text*.

Comment: The problem is `-DLIN = 1` which should be `-DLIN=1`.