# Codeblocks compile error `_Z16draw_hello_worldPvS_` can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, codeblocks

The initial problem is described under the below link.
[Initial problem description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69074832/set-up-codeblocks-linux-mint-for-x-plane-11-sdk/69083829#69083829)

I have corrected the typo regarding LIN = 1 => LIN=1 which leads to this new error message:

```
-------------- Build: Release in HW (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++ -shared -L/home/shj/Dokumente/HelloWorld/SDK/CHeaders/Widgets -L/home/shj/Dokumente/HelloWorld/SDK/CHeaders/Wrappers -L/home/shj/Dokumente/HelloWorld/SDK/CHeaders/XPLM obj/Release/HelloWorld/Hello-World-SDK-3.o  -o bin/Release/liblin.so -s -shared -rdynamic -nodefaultlibs -undefined_warning -lGL -lGLU  
/usr/bin/ld: obj/Release/HelloWorld/Hello-World-SDK-3.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_Z16draw_hello_worldPvS_' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Perhaps somebody can provide some further help.
Many thanks in advance

Comment: As the error suggests, add -fPIC option while compiling.

Comment: The error message itself contains a hint about a way to solve the problem (build with `-fPIC`), have you tried it?

Comment: Adding -fPIC to the Project-Other linker options returns the initial error message, i.e. g++: error: =: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden (fiel or path not found)

Comment: Just noticed that the error message as shown in the caption disappeared, i.e. add -fPIC. When compiling now there is no difference in the current error message, i.e. g++: error: =: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden (fiel or path not found) no matter if -fPIC was added or not

Comment: My apologies for the confusion in the previous comment. Noted that the correction of the typo was not saved,. Error message after adding -fPIC to 'Other linker options' is: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.