# Codeblocks Linux compiler error message (use with SDK for X Plane 11)

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks

When compiling with Codeblocks Linux (Mint) I get the following error message:

```
-------------- Build: Release in HW (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++ -Wall -O2 -DXPLM200=1 -DXPLM210=1 -DXPLM300=1 -DXPLM301=1 -DXPLM302=1 -DXPLM303=1 -DLIN=1 -DIBM=0 -DAPL=0 -I/home/shj/Dokumente/HelloWorld/SDK/CHeaders/Widgets -I/home/shj/Dokumente/HelloWorld/SDK/CHeaders/Wrappers -I/home/shj/Dokumente/HelloWorld/SDK/CHeaders/XPLM -c /home/shj/Dokumente/HelloWorld/Hello-World-SDK-3.cpp -o obj/Release/HelloWorld/Hello-World-SDK-3.o
g++ -shared -L/home/shj/Dokumente/HelloWorld/SDK/CHeaders/Widgets -L/home/shj/Dokumente/HelloWorld/SDK/CHeaders/Wrappers -L/home/shj/Dokumente/HelloWorld/SDK/CHeaders/XPLM obj/Release/HelloWorld/Hello-World-SDK-3.o  -o bin/Release/liblin.so -s -shared -rdynamic -nodefaultlibs -undefined_warning -lGL -lGLU -fPIC  
/home/shj/Dokumente/HelloWorld/Hello-World-SDK-3.cpp: In function ‘void draw_hello_world(XPLMWindowID, void*)’:
/home/shj/Dokumente/HelloWorld/Hello-World-SDK-3.cpp:108:44: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
  108 |  XPLMDrawString(col_white, l + 10, t - 20, "Hello world!", NULL, xplmFont_Proportional);
      |                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/ld: obj/Release/HelloWorld/Hello-World-SDK-3.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_Z16draw_hello_worldPvS_' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
1 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Putting -fPIC in the `Project build settings-Other linker options` does not change the result (not sure where this is the right place as I am new on Linux and CB for Linux).

[Initial problem description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69074832/set-up-codeblocks-linux-mint-for-x-plane-11-sdk)

Typo as mentioned in comments there was corrected.

Comment: Try adding the same flag to compiler flags.

Comment: You have `-fPIC` on the wrong step. You first compile to object with `-fPIC`, e.g. `g++ -Wall -fPIC -c sources.c -o sources.o` Then you compile the shared object library with `g++ -shared -Wl,(linker options, if any) -o yoursharelib.so sources.o`